# What would make people care about a superhero's secret identity?

Tags: super-powers

A superhero appears and saves people in a city. Some people will love the superhero. Some will not. But would people actually care about a superhero's secret identity or alter ego? If so, who would they be and why would they want to find out? Will the superhero's fans care? Will the government care only if the superhero is actually bad?

Comment: Welcome AnP. Questions about the actions or motivations of characters are inherently opinion-based and are regarded as off-topic here, sorry. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Tony Stark once told the world he is Iron Man and even gave his address, guess what, Pepper and many other almost got killed during the "siege" because of his arrogance!

Comment: I would pretty much say "who wouldn't?". Companies want the superhero to use their products on TV and internet, fans want autographs, pictures and paraphernalia from the hero, governments and scientists want their DNA and lots of investigations in their biology and whatever makes their physics odd around them. The entire justice system wants to be able to either call the hero for help or be able to hold them accountable while people with power or criminals want to (ab)use the hero's power.

Comment: What would make people NOT care about a superhero's secret identity?

Answer (score 5):

## Most people would want to know

Seeing the amount of fanboys, magazines of private life's, news and whole forums discussing private lifes, not to mention interested lawmen and the criminal circuit seeing great opportunities to abuse or use a powerful person, I would say nearly everyone.

Government want to know especially as you can only take the law in your own hand in special circumstances. Even if you do it correctly they want your account of it. As the power is on a secret person they very much like to know who it is if control is necessary or simply advantageous.

Answer (score 3):

## Lawyers

trying to sue them for collateral damage that happened while they were Saving The Day; for flying without a pilots license; for infringing copyright on the trademarked design of the action figures that BigMerchCorp is selling.

Answer (score 2):

> [It is kept hidden from their enemies and the general public to protect themselves from legal ramifications, pressure, or public scrutiny, as well as to protect their friends and loved ones from harm secondary to their actions as superheroes.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_identity)

Answer (score 2):

Ever pick up and read a tabloid?

Humans are, by nature, very curious. They want to know and will seek out the most juiciest of stories to satisfy their curiosity.

Beyond the other answers that give basically obvious answers such as the government, law enforcement, lawyers etc. its Joe Shmoo that would want to know out of pure morbid curiosity. Paparazzi would hound such people to get the skinny their story and they would not have any concern about what lives they destroy to get the story.

Answer (score 0):

The secret identity is more for the superhero; so they can live a normal life when they aren't saving the world.

Because, ask most super-celebrities, humans can be endlessly obsessive and intrusive. The superhero doesn't want throngs of worshipers at their doorstep all day, insisting the superhero is their soul mate, begging for miracles the superhero cannot deliver, begging for "blessings" the superhero knows don't do any good.

The superhero doesn't want the opposite, protesters screaming at them to go home, claiming they are the devil incarnate, claiming the good deeds they did are a fraud, a con, a deep state plot to take over the world.

The superhero just wants to fly the terrorist nukes into the sun, go home, make some popcorn and watch a rerun of Seinfeld before they hit the sack.

Is that too much to ask?

Comment: Just compare to any rock singer before they make it big and after. Afterwards, they have to lock the doors and have security to keep them safe.